# In HDFS: How to check if 2 directories have same parent directory

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hdfs

Is there a HDFS command  to check if 2 directories in HDFS have common parent directory.

eg:

```
$ hadoop fs -ls -R  /user/username/data/
/user/username/data/LIST_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533057294, 
/user/username/data/LIST_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533873826/UI,
/user/username/data/LIST_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533873826/NEWDATA/A,
/user/username/data/LIST_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533873826/NEWDATA/A/N,
/user/username/data/LIST_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533873826/NEWDATA/M/K/L,
/user/username/data/LIST_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533873826/NEWDATA/O/P/P,
/user/username/data/LIST_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533873826/NEWDATA/wkejdhew,
/user/username/data/LIST_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533873826/NEWDATA/oi32u,
/user/username/data/ARRAY_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533057294, 
/user/username/data/ARRAY_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533873826/UI,
/user/username/data/ARRAY_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533873826/NEWDATA/A,
/user/username/data/ARRAY_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533873826/NEWDATA/A/N,
/user/username/data/ARRAY_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533873826/NEWDATA/M/K/L,
/user/username/data/ARRAY_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533873826/NEWDATA/O/P/P,
/user/username/data/ARRAY_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533873826/NEWDATA/wkejdhew,
/user/username/data/ARRAY_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533873826/NEWDATA/oi32u,
```

All these directories share same parent dir `/user/username/data/LIST_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533057294` and `/user/username/data/ARRAY_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533057294`. How can we check that in bash?

Comment: is [dirname](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) and [string comparison](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test) not enough for hdfs?

Comment: @KamilCuk hi I edited the question to include another directory /user/username/data/LIST_1539724717/SUBLIST_1533873826/NEWDATA, in this case my script  should check if parent directory /user/username/data/LIST_1539724717 is same for all 3 directories, dirname will not help here , since it gives me directory name one level up

Comment: Have you thought of running it twice then? So how many parent directories must be the same for files have the same parent? All files are in the root directory, so there is always a parent-parent-parent-parent-dir common.

Comment: Actually, i am running hadoop fs -ls -R /user/username/data/LIST_1539724717/ so there will be parent-parent-parent-parent directory , but i want the 1st parent directory of hadoop fs -ls -R /user/username/data/LIST_1539724717/  .. edited question .

Comment: You can filter from the list only the first 5 levels of directories/entries and then get unique lines only. You will be left with only to lines, or more.

Comment: Can't you use stat(1)?

Comment: As in stat --format "%i" $(dirname FILE1) and stat --format "%i" $(dirname FILE2).

Comment: @Roadowl stat and dirname don't work like that for HDFS.

Comment: You would have to use AWK or other language to parse this output. There's no direct HDFS cli to get this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating shell script where directory name can be passed as a variable, we can check if both belongs to same parent or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
for value in `hadoop fs -ls ${DIR}| awk '{print $NF}' | tr '\n' ' '`
do
    if [ "$value" != "items" ]; then
        #add values into "results" array
        log "info" "$value"
        results+=("$value")
    fi
done

#Loop through each value inside the array ie " $DIR"
for i in "${results[@]}"
do
    oldVal=`hadoop fs -ls -R ${i} | sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -d\  -f 1,8 --output-delimiter=',' | grep ^d | cut -d, -f2`
    log "info" "Checking sub-directories under $i ! "
    #This takes the directory name as its input and extract the directories only for the provided runID
        for val in `hadoop fs -ls -R $i  | grep  1539724717 |sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -d\  -f 1,8 --output-delimiter=',' | grep ^d | cut -d, -f2`
          do

           if [[ ! ${val} =~ ${oldVal} ]]; then
               oldVal=$val
               directory+=("${oldVal}")
           fi
        done
done
```

`directory` array contains all directories needed.